# как вернуть пароль по имени и фамилии пользователя?

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite, sqlite3

есть код:

```
import sqlite3
id = 0
string = 'null'

with sqlite3.connect('licey/newbase.db') as db:
    cursor = db.cursor()
    while string != 'stop':
        string = input()
        if string == 'create':
            cursor.execute(""" CREATE TABLE users( name TEXT, surname TEXT, password TEXT); """)
            db.commit()
        if 'запиши' in string:
            surname = input()
            password = input()
            cursor.execute(f""" INSERT INTO users (name, surname, password) VALUES('{string[7:]}', '{surname}', '{password}'); """)
            id += 1
        db.commit()
        if 'покажи' in string:
            surname = input()
            password = input()
            cursor.execute(f""" SELECT name, surname, password FROM users WHERE name == '{string[7:]}' and surname == '{surname}'; """)
            result = cursor.fetchall()
            if str(result) == '[]':
                print('Пользователь не найден!')
            else:
                print('ок ' + str(result))
```

нужно чтобы он проверял, если пользователь ввёл имя и фамилию, то должен выводится его пароль.
Как это сделать?
если можно скиньте сразу код, просто я новичок в этом деле.

Comment: `if str(result) == '[]':` жесть :) Проще ведь проверить на пустой список: `if not result:`. А вместо `cursor.execute(f""" INSERT INTO users (name, surname, password) VALUES('{string[7:]}', '{surname}', '{password}'); """)`  можно ведь просто `if not result:` можно просто `cursor.execute(""" INSERT INTO users (name, surname, password) VALUES(?, ?, ?); """, [string[7:], surname, password])`, так надежнее и нагляднее.

Comment: я примерно код накидал, меня интересует это:
есть таблица
---------------------------------
|name|surname|password|
-----------------------------------
|user1|sern1     |pass1|
------------------------------------

я ввожу user1 и sern1, и мне нужно чтобы он вывел pass1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для возвращения пароля из таблицы базы можно выполнить такой запрос, где `name` и `surname` введенные имя и фамилия:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT password FROM users WHERE name = ? and surname = ?", [name, surname])
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло

Comment: @ЕгорКолесников, пожалуйста, и не забудьте [проголосовать и принять ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: а вы за вопрос)